# when i select favourites images, then scroll-up and automatically multiple images selected

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase-realtime-database

- When i select favourites images, then scroll-up and automatically multiple images selected

```
dbWallpapers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("images")
                .child(category);


        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null){
            dbFavs = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
                    .child( FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() )
                    .child( "favourites" )
                    .child( category );

            fetchFavWallpapers( category );
        }else {
            fetchWallpapers( category );
        }
    }

    private  void fetchFavWallpapers(final String category){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dbFavs.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot wallpaperSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        String id = wallpaperSnapshot.getKey();
                        String title = wallpaperSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                        String desc = wallpaperSnapshot.child("desc").getValue(String.class);
                        String url = wallpaperSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);


                        Wallpaper w = new Wallpaper( id, id, title, desc,url, category);
                        favList.add(w);
                    }
                }
                fetchWallpapers( category );
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: try creating a local String object inside fetchFavWallpapers() and assign category to it. And then remove final from final String category. use the local object instead

Comment: What's the question? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo my question is? I check one images is favourites and automatically multiple images favourites

Comment: @RohitRawat when i remove final on string category. And many errors occur on category.. And not to assign another object

Comment: Please write a code how to assign in local objects???